# Tapping Multiple Buttons in Custom UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, selector

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass where I am putting two buttons in the cell, I want both to be clickable, but so far I cannot even get any kind of click to trigger (besides row selection, but I disabled that on my UITableViewController subclass). Basically When one of two buttons is selected, it should remove those two buttons and update what is in the cell with a list of selectable choices (also buttons). I am doing everything programmatically (no IB).

[My TableViewCell with Initial Two Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDe7m.png)

I have looked around a lot and haven't found anything that handles more than ONE button in a tableViewCell. Currently I've been trying to add targets to my buttons in my UITableViewCell's awakeFromNib():

```
for button in initialChoiceButtons{
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(initialChoicePressed(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        }
```

One thing I've tried is in my tableView in cellForRowAt for my custom cell is to bring my buttons to the front of the cell:

```
for button in (cell as! FormDropDownTableViewCell).initialChoiceButtons{
                    cell.bringSubview(toFront: button)
                }
```

I'm really stumped and feel like this should easy. I'm on the verge of just using a stackView inside of scrollview for everything...

Comment: Ok so I just got this working with my multiple buttons in a tableviewcell by basically add the targets to my buttons in cellForRowAt and moving my action method into my tableviewcontroller. The problem with this is, I would like the functionality to be separated between my tableviewcell and tableviewcontroller. Right now to get this working I'm forced to do this in my action function in my tableviewcontroller:  

(sender.superview!.superview!.superview!.superview as! FormDropDownTableViewCell).showSelectionButtons()

Comment: ^^(sender is UIButton) and then superviews are VerticalStackView, HorizontalStackView, ContentView, UITableViewCell .. there has to be a better way where I can keep my actual action method inside my tableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out a somewhat clean way to separate button taps in my tableviewcell, by creating a delegate protocol with a function that I'll call from my target in my tableviewcontroller for every button in my tableviewcell.

```
protocol UIButtonSelectorDelegate{
    func handleTap(button:DelegatingButton) //will select different functions based on DelegatingButton.actionType
}
class DelegatingButton:UIButton{
    var selectorDelegate:UIButtonSelectorDelegate?
    var actionType:String = "default"
}
```

in my FormDropDownTableViewCell I conform to the UIButtonSelectedDelegate and implement handleTap like so:

```
func handleTap(button:DelegatingButton){
        switch button.actionType{
        case "initialChoiceSelect":
            initialChoicePressed(initialChoice:button) //specific method for certain button.actionType also in my FormDropDownTableViewCell
        case "cardTypeSelect":
            cardTypeSelected(selectedCardType:button)
        default:
            break

        }
    }
```

Now I add the target-actions for every button in cellForRowAt in my tableviewcontroller like so:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonTaps), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

and the handleButtonTaps func in the tableviewcontroller is simple:

```
func handleButtonTaps(sender: DelegatingButton){
        sender.selectorDelegate?.handleTap(button: sender)
    }
```

Enjoyed Talking to myself =P ..